# codeigniter session wont set

Tags: session, codeigniter, set

Hello i try to set session with some values but i will not set my session :S and yes my $tjek_login is true

```
    if($tjek_login === true)
  {
   $session_data = array(
    'username'         => $username,
    'ip_adresse'       => $this->input->ip_address(),
    'sidst_aktivitet'  => 'hm',
    'logget_ind'       => true
   );

   $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);

   $test = $this->session->userdata($session_data);
   echo $test;

   if($test === true)
   {
    echo "ja";
   } else {
    echo "nej";
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, using [=== operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) on `$this->session->userdata($session_data)` would not return true if the data is there.

Try doing `if($this->session->userdata($session_data))` instead.

Also, instead of `echo $test;` try `var_dump($test);`

Sample Code:

```
    if($tjek_login === true)
  {
   $session_data = array(
    'username'         => $username,
    'ip_adresse'       => $this->input->ip_address(),
    'sidst_aktivitet'  => 'hm',
    'logget_ind'       => true
   );

   $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);

   $test = $this->session->userdata($session_data);
   var_dump($test);

   if($test)
   {
    echo "ja";
   } else {
    echo "nej";
   }
```